# tf.reshape doesn't work as expected

Tags: tensorflow

Actually, I don't know how to describe this question. It's so strange.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pickle

def weight_and_bias(name ,shape):
    weight = tf.get_variable("W" + name, shape=shape, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    bias = tf.get_variable("B" + name, shape=shape[-1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    return weight, bias

def conv2d_2x2(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 5, 5, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

source = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 50, 50])
source_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
source_max_step = tf.shape(source)[1]

target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 50, 50])
target_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
target_max_step = tf.shape(target)[1]

W_conv, B_conv = weight_and_bias('conv1', [5, 5, 1, 32])

source = tf.reshape(source, [-1, 50, 50], "source_reshape")
source_tmp = tf.reshape(source, [-1, 50, 50 ,1])
source_conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_2x2(source_tmp, W_conv) + B_conv)
source_pool = max_pool_2x2(source_conv)
source_flat = tf.reshape(source_pool, [-1, 5 * 5 * 32], "source_pool_reshape")
source = tf.reshape(source_flat, [-1, source_max_step, 5*5*32], "source_flat_reshape")

W_conv, B_conv = weight_and_bias('conv2', [5, 5, 1, 32])

target = tf.reshape(target, [-1, 50, 50], "target_reshape")
target_tmp = tf.reshape(target, [-1, 50, 50 ,1])
target_conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_2x2(target_tmp, W_conv) + B_conv)
target_pool = max_pool_2x2(target_conv)
target_flat = tf.reshape(target_pool, [-1, 5 * 5 * 32], "target_pool_reshape")
target = tf.reshape(target_flat, [-1, target_max_step, 5*5*32], "target_flat_reshape")

source_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(500, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
target_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(500, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
source_rnn_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(source_cell, source, source_len, dtype=tf.float32, scope = "source")
target_rnn_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(target_cell, target, target_len, dtype=tf.float32, scope = "target")

source_output = tf.transpose(source_rnn_output, [1, 0, 2])
target_output = tf.transpose(target_rnn_output, [1, 0, 2])

source_final_output = tf.gather(source_output, -1)
target_final_output = tf.gather(target_output, -1)

output = tf.concat(1, [source_final_output, target_final_output])

W_sf, B_sf = weight_and_bias('sf', [1000, 2])
predict = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output, W_sf) + B_sf)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(predict))
train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(predict, 1), tf.arg_max(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with open('set', 'rb') as f:
    _set = pickle.load(f)
    training_set = _set[0]
    training_len = _set[1]
    training_label = _set[2]

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(20000):

    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuacy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {source: training_set[0], target: training_set[1], source_len: training_len[0], target_len: training_len[1], y: training_label})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuacy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict = {source: training_set[0], target: training_set[1], source_len: training_len[0], target_len: training_len[1], y: training_label})
```

These are my whole code, I can't find any problem in it.

But a `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1077, 27, 50, 50) for Tensor 'source_flat_reshape:0', which has shape '(?, ?, 800)'` was raised.

The error message is strange, because it seems happen at `source = tf.reshape(source_flat, [-1, source_max_step, 5*5*32], "source_flat_reshape")`, but how could `source_flat` has a shape of `(1077, 27, 50, 50)`? It should be `(1077*77, 800)`

And, sometimes another `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1077, 27, 50, 50) for Tensor 'Reshape:0', which has shape '(?, 50, 50)'` was raised.

It is also difficult to understand, why it happened?

Hope anyone could give me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what happens when you use `feed_dict` - you reference the variables `source` and `target`. However, the python variable no longer refers to the placeholders but rather the reshape ops - hence the op is 'skipped'.

The easiest fix is renaming the placeholders to something unique. Further down in the network it is OK to reuse the same name (you could just call every layer `net`), it doesn't matter as long as you no longer need to reference them.

Try giving this a go?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pickle

def weight_and_bias(name ,shape):
    weight = tf.get_variable("W" + name, shape=shape, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    bias = tf.get_variable("B" + name, shape=shape[-1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    return weight, bias

def conv2d_2x2(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 5, 5, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

source_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 50, 50])
source_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
source_max_step = tf.shape(source)[1]

target_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 50, 50])
target_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
target_max_step = tf.shape(target)[1]

W_conv, B_conv = weight_and_bias('conv1', [5, 5, 1, 32])

source = tf.reshape(source_placeholder, [-1, 50, 50], "source_reshape")
source_tmp = tf.reshape(source, [-1, 50, 50 ,1])
source_conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_2x2(source_tmp, W_conv) + B_conv)
source_pool = max_pool_2x2(source_conv)
source_flat = tf.reshape(source_pool, [-1, 5 * 5 * 32], "source_pool_reshape")
source = tf.reshape(source_flat, [-1, source_max_step, 5*5*32], "source_flat_reshape")

W_conv, B_conv = weight_and_bias('conv2', [5, 5, 1, 32])

target = tf.reshape(target_placeholder, [-1, 50, 50], "target_reshape")
target_tmp = tf.reshape(target, [-1, 50, 50 ,1])
target_conv = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_2x2(target_tmp, W_conv) + B_conv)
target_pool = max_pool_2x2(target_conv)
target_flat = tf.reshape(target_pool, [-1, 5 * 5 * 32], "target_pool_reshape")
target = tf.reshape(target_flat, [-1, target_max_step, 5*5*32], "target_flat_reshape")

source_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(500, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
target_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(500, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
source_rnn_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(source_cell, source, source_len, dtype=tf.float32, scope = "source")
target_rnn_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(target_cell, target, target_len, dtype=tf.float32, scope = "target")

source_output = tf.transpose(source_rnn_output, [1, 0, 2])
target_output = tf.transpose(target_rnn_output, [1, 0, 2])

source_final_output = tf.gather(source_output, -1)
target_final_output = tf.gather(target_output, -1)

output = tf.concat(1, [source_final_output, target_final_output])

W_sf, B_sf = weight_and_bias('sf', [1000, 2])
predict = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output, W_sf) + B_sf)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(predict))
train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(predict, 1), tf.arg_max(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with open('set', 'rb') as f:
    _set = pickle.load(f)
    training_set = _set[0]
    training_len = _set[1]
    training_label = _set[2]

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(20000):

    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuacy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {source_placeholder: training_set[0], target_placeholder: training_set[1], source_len: training_len[0], target_len: training_len[1], y: training_label})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuacy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict = {source_placeholder: training_set[0], target_placeholder: training_set[1], source_len: training_len[0], target_len: training_len[1], y: training_label})
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Yesterday I finally find the problem. The placehold is exactly where the problem is.